# Ajax Confusing http status

Tags: php, ajax

I have a register form and I want to show some messages in a div. I use Ajax for this. The confusing fact is that in the ajax block, it enters on 'error' branch and show http status 200. It is ok to do that? The submit event is on the form. Should I put on the button? How can I fix it to do what I want?

```
<form id="register" class="modall-content animate" action="register.php" method="post">
......
<div id = "error-reg"></div>
<div id = "success-reg"></div>
</form>
```

Php code is this

```
if(isset($_POST['btn-rg'])) {
..
 if ($count == 0) {
    if ($check == 1)
        $query = "INSERT INTO ...";
    elseif ($check == 2)
        $query = "INSERT INTO ...";
    else {
        $query = "INSERT INTO ...";
    }

    if ($db->query($query)) {
        $success .= "Success";
        /*echo $success;*/
        echo json_encode(array("success" => $success));
    }

} else {
    $message .= "Username already exists";
     /*echo $message;*/
    echo json_encode(array("message" => $message));
}

/*$response = array();
$response['success'] = $success;
$response['errors']  = $message;
echo(json_encode($response));*/
}
```

And my js

```
$("#register").on('submit',function (event) {

event.preventDefault();
var dataPost= $('#register').serialize();
$.ajax({
    url: 'register.php',
    type: 'post',
    dataType : 'json',
    data: dataPost,
    success: function(data) {
        if (response.success) {
            $('#error-reg').hide();
            $('#success-reg').html(response.success).css('color','green');
        } else {
            $('#error-reg').html(response.errors);

        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});

});
```

When I make the submit this is what I get

[image]

Comment: What is the response you get from the ajax call?

Comment: A submit event belongs on the form. The php response should be on een echo statement.
`echo json_encode( ... )`

Comment: The response is data from the error branch.

Comment: I changed 'exit' to 'echo', but the same..

Comment: @Alina - How about using `echo json_encode` in your other branch .. You should use an array there too. -- `echo json_encode($array)`

Comment: What are you expecting the output of your php script to be? It's not going to be valid json

Comment: Why?And how to fix?

Comment: When Ajax receives the response from your script, that includes all output. You're echoing stuff out before you json encode it. So you're getting 200 response, but not the data you expect.

Comment: And how to fix that to work?

Comment: Not on my computer, so I can't verify this would generate error, but it seems likely

Comment: My thought is to get rid of the extraneous output and print only the json

Comment: I have updated my post with the new code, but I have the same problem

Comment: Use developer tools on your browser to see what the response is.

Comment: Btw is the insert successful

Comment: @Alina - Another thing I see is that you use JSON.parse() ... Your dataType is already set to 'json'. That is like double .. Take JSON.parse out and refer to the response as `data.success`, `data.message` (dot notation).

Comment: The response is 200. I made your changes, @Daniel, but still doesn't work.

Comment: Insert works if I don't use ajax

Comment: Ah, so your script is not receiving good data in the first place.  So you've got more than one issue. I'll look at this more when I get to a computer.

Comment: Thank you. I will wait for an answer

Comment: At this point, it looks like Daniel is taking you through the troubleshooting, so I'll keep it simple by not confusing you with multiple threads.  When debugging, it's much easier to debug one thing a time ;)

Comment: @TimMorton - Thanks Tim ... Just seemed like a stepwise process was rhe best approach. Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you very much all! You helped me with a problem that I had from a couple of days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `register.php` right at the top.

Keep this code, but comment it out.It will give you access to see and make sure what comes in.

```
   // echo json_encode($_POST);
  //  exit;
```

You did see `$_POST['btn-rg']`???  ---> NO !!

Did you declare your HTML button as an input?

```
<input type='submit' name='btn-rg' value='Submit'>
```

Now take the folowng lines and put it in top of the if-statement. I want to be sure we get inside this statement. You should expect to see "hello world " again.

```
echo json_encode(array("message" => "hello world"));
exit;
```

Comment: Yes, the first solution with echo works..It shows me the message 'hello world' in the console.

Comment: Great .. It's alive ;-) .. That means that it goes wrong in your PHP.
I changed to post for further troubleshoot.

Comment: In the console, I have the inputs that I introduce in the form

Comment: Next step ...  ;-)

Comment: No, I don't see the $_POST['btn-rg']. 'btn-rg' is the id for the submit button and if I put the code in if-statement, it doesn't show anything.

Comment: That is your problem. make sure you declared the correct HTML in your form. See the adjustment.

Comment: Thank you, @Daniel! Thank you for your patience to make with me baby steps and solve my problem.:)

Comment: I have <buton type='submit' name='btn-rg'>

Comment: So I guess you got it solved and working now? .. You're welcome. Happy coding!